# Does Node Red on Bluemix allow for a connection to MessageHub MQLight topic?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, message-hub

I have created a MessageHub service in Bluemix and bound a Node Red application, also in Bluemix.  In MH I added an MQLight topic.  When I try to connect the mqlight node provided in Node Red it says MQ Light service not available.  Does the mqlight node have the ability to connect to a MessageHub service with a topic of MQLight?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the MessageHub node for your Node-Red flow instead of the MQ Light node? MQ Light service in Bluemix was deprecated and now the recommended messaging service for Bluemix is MessageHub.  Try adding the [MessageHub node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-messagehub) to your flow - in your Node-red editor you can select Manage Palette from the menu (top right), and then select the install tab in the palette. Search for messageHub node to install and then configure to use your MQLight topic.

Comment: Yes I did but maybe I'm missing something as it only looked like it was an output node...and even that was unclear how to connect.  I really looking for an input node to receive messages from message hub.  Have you seen it work in that way...or work at all?